# Mozilla Thunderbird not opening p7m attachment of encrypted emails

Tags: thunderbird, smime

When I receive an encrypted and signed email in Thunderbird, I can only see smime.p7m file attachment and no message.

Mozilla should automatically decrypt and display the message (provided I have correct private key). I am talking about S/MIME here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug since version 60.0. Luckily it can be fixed:

- go to *Tools -> Options*
- select *Advanced -> General*
- click *Config Editor...*
- click *I accept the risk!*
- search for *"p7m"*
- select second line which should be like *"mailnews.p7m_subparts_external"*
- change value to **false**

Now restart Thunderbird and emails should be automatically decrypted like before.